# Strong params and security

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

In a controller method I have:

```
@user = current_user
@rel = Relationship.where('user_id = ? and organization_id = ? and fish = ?', @user.id, params[:user][:default_relationship_id], true).first
@user.update_attributes(default_relationship_id: @rel.id)
```

I understand the last line is not secure and requires strong parameters to prevent mass assignment (meaning a user could set any other db variable for that user as well). But how to refactor to make this secure (in this case and more general)?

If I am correct there are two ways: 1) by replacing it with strong params, or 2) by using a model method.

**Ad 1) Strong params:**

```
@user.update_attributes(update_params)
private
  def update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:default_relationship_id)
  end
```

But how would this know to set `default_relationship_id` to `@rel.id`?

**Ad 2) Add it to a model method:**

```
@user.update_default(@rel.id)     # In controller

def update_default(value)         # In model file
  self.update_attributes(default_relationship_id: value)
end
```

But would this indeed be secure since it's not a private model method?

*Could someone explain the question I have for each of the two approaches, and perhaps explain which approach is preferred?*

Comment: But you have no mass assignment is your example, you're taking the id value from the `@rel`

Comment: As Yury says, you're not using any user input so you don't have any mass assignment problems.

Comment: But `@rel` is based on user input (see the params used on that line) and `@rel` is used to determine the value for `default_relationship_id`. Or does that not matter, and is the possibility of unwanted mass assignment only an issue if you directly update a value on basis of user input (instead of the "indirect" way in my example)?

Comment: `@rel.id` is not directly based on user input, it is taken from the database

Comment: take a look at the answer from Frederick Cheung, he explained why is the protection for mass assignment needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strong params is for mass assignment, i.e. it is for cases like this

```
some_user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

where the user might have manipulated the form to include extra values. What you're doing isn't mass assignment, so strong params is not relevant. In addition strong params doesn't check the content of the parameters (except for checking that values are scalars).

You may still want to check that is ok for the user to set their `default_relationship_id` to that value, but you'll need to implement those checks yourself. Neither of your 2 suggestions add any security (which may be fine if the query populating `@rel` will only return objects the user is allowed to associated with)